# Simple present for an activity up to now

Tags: present-simple

One of my friend is posting his pictures in facebook for over a long period of time.

When I see him tomorrow, can I tell him like " hi friend, how are you? I see your pictures in Facebook.

Comment: BTW, we *tell* someone {a truth or a lie}.  We do not "tell" a greeting. So you would ask, "When I see him tomorrow, can I *say* to him, 'How are you?' and then  *tell* him that I see his pictures on Facebook?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say:

> I see your pictures **on** Facebook.

Not "in."

Since you've been looking at the photos over a long period of time, it might be better to say this:

> I've been seeing your pictures on Facebook.
>
> I've been looking at your pictures on Facebook.

*I've been seeing* means you've been doing it for a period of time, including now and in the past.

Comment: Why on Facebook, not in facebook?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly. It's a good question. You read words *in a book*, not *on a book*. But if you create a user profile, you put it *on LinkedIn*. And if you create a new web page, you put it *onto* your server. You can *I did a search in Google*, but I think it's more common to say *I did a search on Google*. I think it comes from the idea that you go *to* a web page, not *into* the web page. And once the page has loaded, you are *on* a web page, not *in* the web page. Kind of fascinating when you think about it.

Comment: What about the verb "fallow"? I fallow your...

Comment: It may have something to do with the difference between computer applications and websites. For example, if you're using Microsoft Word, you don't usually say *I'm on Word.* You say, *I'm in Word.* Same with video games. You say, *I'm in the game,* or *I'm in world*. Websites are so crappy compared to video games and desktop applications. Websites aren't immersive, and psychologically we might be thinking we're *on* something instead of immersed inside of it.

Comment: @Sina  "Follow" (not "fallow") already contains the idea of an action happening over time. You can't "follow" for a moment in time, it's something you do over a period of time. So yes, it's perfectly fine to say *I follow your pictures on Facebook."

Answer (score 1):

> I see your pictures on Facebook.

In this context, the use of [present simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-simple) indicates a habitual action- something that happens again and again. We normally use it with an adverb indicating how frequently, though it's not essential. Here is an example

> I **regularly** see your pictures on Facebook.

This is appropriate if you are not talking about any specific pictures: if the listener posts a picture, you usually see it. If you are talking about a specific group of pictures, for example those for a holiday or a party, you would use either simple past.

> Did you enjoy your holiday? I saw your pictures on Facebook.

or present perfect simple, which implies that seeing the pictures had an effect that lasted to the present.

> You don't need to tell me about it: I have seen your pictures on facebook.